# update progress bar from razor server

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor, progress-bar, razor-pages

I have a progress bar on a razor page.

I know it works because I've called it on an onclick event.

The issue is getting it to work from the server side. Here is the code:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    
    namespace websitename.Pages.test
    {
        public class surmodelModel : PageModel
        {
            public int niter { get; set; } = 50000;
            public int pvalue { get; set; } = 0;        
            public int thecounter = 0;

            public void OnGet()
            {
                Some programming
            }

            public JsonResult OnPost()
            {
                Initial programming

                for (i = 0; i < myniter; i++)
                {
                    More programming
                    ...
                    thecounter++;
                    pvalue = 100 * thecounter / myniter;
                    return new JsonResult(pvalue);
                }
                Final programming
                return new JsonResult(pvalue);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the javascript programming on the view side:

```
    <script>
        function gibbs(){
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(pvalue){
                    var pv = jQuery.parseJSON(pvalue);
                    movebar(pv);
            }})
        }   
        function movebar(pvalue){
            var elem = document.getElementById("mybar");
            var width = pvalue;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame(){
# if (width <= 100) **your text**
                {
                    elem.style.width = width / 2 + '%';
                    elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                }       
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The basic idea is that the progress bar should update after each loop.
Why does it not do that? Any and all insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop returns after each step:

```
                for (i = 0; i < myniter; i++)
                {
                    More programming
                    ...
                    thecounter++;
                    pvalue = 100 * thecounter / myniter;
                    return new JsonResult(pvalue);
                }
```

This means that `i` is initially 0 and after some stuff, `pvalue` is computed and returned. Instead, your server-side should have a way of determining where it is in its progress and return when some progress is made. So, your server should await for an action is completed, that is, a packet is completed and return the actual, computed state to the client. Instead, you start from 0, even if you had some partial progress.

Comment: I added a condition for pvalue to be at least 1. If I set niter = 1, then the view shows only the value 100 and nothing else on the page. If I set niter > 1, then the page becomes blank.

Answer (score 0):

Your current server-side code returns a `JsonResult` inside a loop, which doesn't align with how HTTP responses are handled. You cannot return multiple responses from a single HTTP request by ajax.

For the real-time processing bar, sugget you using SiganlR.

Just a simple demo, you can get started with it and modify for your own scenario.

1. Add SignalR to your ASP.NET Core project: Refer to [the official Microsoft documentation to get started with SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-signalr-client-library).
2. Create a Hub

   ```
    public class ProgressHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendProgress(int progress)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveProgress", progress);
        }
    }
   ```
3. Configure SignalR in Program.cs

   ```
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    builder.Services.AddSignalR();  //add this line....
    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapRazorPages();
    app.MapHub<ProgressHub>("/progressHub");  //add this line...
   ```
4. PageModel

   ```
   public class IndexModel : PageModel
   {
       private readonly IHubContext<ProgressHub> _hubContext;

       public IndexModel(IHubContext<ProgressHub> hubContext)
       {
           _hubContext = hubContext;
       }

       public async Task OnPostAsync()
       {
           for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
           {
               // Your processing logic here
               await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveProgress", i);
               await Task.Delay(100); 
           }
       }

   }
   ```
5. Page

   ```
    @page
    @model IndexModel

    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Start Progress" />
    </form>

    <div id="progressBar" style="width:0%;background-color:green;height:20px"></div>
    @section Scripts
    {
        <!-- change by yourself which depends on your js location --!>
         <script src="~/lib/microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>

        <script>
            const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/progressHub").build();

            connection.on("ReceiveProgress", function (progress) {
                document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width = progress + "%";
                document.getElementById("progressBar").innerText = progress + "%";
            });

            connection.start().catch(function (err) {
                return console.error(err.toString());
            });
        </script>
    }
   ```

Comment: The signalR complies correctly, but I'm afraid no progress bar.

Comment: Hi @Gerry, how is your code like? It works with progress bar successfully.

Comment: Please have a look at the original Q. There is some initial programming before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole nine yards.

First, the progress bar code in the css file:

```
.progress-bar {
    height: 20px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: cyan;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 22px;
}
```

Follow the aforementioned advice to set up signalR. Note further down that I set up a js folder for the signalr.js file.

Here is the code in the hub entitled movebarhub.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace projectname.Hubs
{
    public class MovebarHub: Hub
    {
        public async Task SendProgress(int progress)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveProgress", progress);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the server file:

```
using projectname.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace projectname.Pages.test
{
    public class nameModel : PageModel
    {
        public int niter { get; set; } = 0;
        public int i = 0;
        public int myniter = 50000;
        public int thecounter = 0;
        public int pvalue = 0;        


        public nameModel(IHubContext<MovebarHub> _hubContext)
        {
            hubContext = _hubContext;
        }

         public void OnGet()
        {
            // code here
        }

        public async Task OnPostAsync(int pvalue)
        {
            myniter = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["niter"]);

            // more code here

            for (i = 0; i < myniter; i++)
            {
                thecounter++;
                pvalue = 100 * thecounter / myniter;
                await hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveProgress", pvalue);
            }
        
            // more code here
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the client file:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" asp-for="niter" value="@Model.myniter" />
    <p><button type="Submit" id="startbar">Submit</button></p>
</form>

<div id="mybar" class="progress-bar"></div>

<p>Result:<br> 
// html output</p>

<script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>

<script>
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/movebarhub").build();

    //Disable the send button until connection is established.
    document.getElementById("startbar").disabled = true;

    connection.on("ReceiveProgress", function (pvalue) {
        var elem = document.getElementById("mybar");
        var width = pvalue;
        if (width <= 100) 
        {
            elem.style.width = width / 2 + '%';
            elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    });

    connection.start().then(function () {
        document.getElementById("startbar").disabled = false;
    });
</script>
```

It should be noted that the progress bar disappears after the output is derived.